# Need help to clean up all unwanted nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I'm relatively new using Ubuntu and I'm trying to understand those drivers and GPUs.

I need to install the `nvidia 390` in my Ubuntu 20.04. But it seems to have a lot of other drives installed by me, I'm still learning.

How can I see my available GPUs, choose one to use by default, remove all the unwanted drivers and install only the `nvidia 390`?

If there are some missing information, just comment below and I'll print here as an update to this question.

**Update**

Here is the list of nvidia dpkg:

```
@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-450                       450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-450:amd64                450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                  390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                  390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-450:amd64                  450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                    390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                      390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                    390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-450                   450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-450                            450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-450                   450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-modprobe                            440.44-1                              amd64        utility to load NVIDIA kernel modules and create device nodes
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.14                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Here is another update with more informations:

```
@ubuntu:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GeForce 820M
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
0a:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: They are not installed. They are available for installation.

Comment: How can I list the installed ones?

Comment: The 390 is installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: So, update done. Hope it helps me to understand more about my GPUs and drivers. Which one of those am I using by default?

Comment: You are using Intel. The Nvidia driver is not in use because `nvidia-prime` disabled it, or secure noot is on. What does `prime-select query` show?

Comment: `prime-select query` shows `nvidia`

Comment: How can I deal with secure boot?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The 390 Nvidia driver is installed as you can see by `ii` mark.

There is nothing else to do.

The only one package that doesn't seem to be of any use is `libnvidia-common-450`. But it shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: But why do I get this error then: @ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Maybe because Secure Boot is on.

Comment: If that's really your question you should ask that instead.